# What is the difference between dataframe.series and dataframe['series']?

Tags: python, pandas

I just tried sorting my dataframe and used the following function:

```
df[df.count >= df.count.quantile(.95)]
```

It returned the error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'quantile'
```

But bracketing the series works fine:

```
df[df['count'] >= df['count'].quantile(.95)]
```

It's not the first time I've gotten different results based on this distinction, but it also usually doesn't happen, and I always thought that these were two identical objects.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `count` is one of data frame's built in method, when you use `.` it is recognized as the method instead of the column *count*, i.e, `.` prioritize built-in method over columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':[1,2,3],
    'B':[2,3,4],
    'count': [4,5,6]
})

df.count()
#A        3
#B        3
#count    3
#dtype: int64

df.count
#              V V V V V V V V
#<bound method DataFrame.count of    A  B  count
#0  1  2      4
#1  2  3      5
#2  3  4      6>
```

---

Another distinction between dot and bracket is, you can not use dot to create a new column. i.e. if the column doesn't exist, `df.column = ...` won't work, you have to use bracket in this case. as `df[column] = ...`, using the above dummy data frame:

```
# original data frame
df
#   A   B   count
#0  1   2   4
#1  2   3   5
#2  3   4   6
```

Using dot to create a new column won't work, C is set as an attribute instead of a column:

```
df.C = 2    
df
#   A   B   count
#0  1   2       4
#1  2   3       5
#2  3   4       6
```

While bracket is the standard way to add a new column to the data frame:

```
df['C'] = 2
df
#   A   B   count   C
#0  1   2       4   2
#1  2   3       5   2
#2  3   4       6   2
```

If a column already exists, it's valid to modify it with dot assuming the data frame doesn't have an attribute with the same name (as is the case of the *count* above):

```
df.B = 3    
df
#   A   B   count   C
#0  1   3       4   2
#1  2   3       5   2
#2  3   3       6   2
```

Comment: That makes sense. Is there any other distinction between the two? For example, using df.series = df.series.str.replace(string, replace) doesn't return my series in the dataframe, but bracketing does.

Comment: Another distinction between dot and bracket is, you can not use dot to create a new column. i.e. if the column doesn't exist, `df.column = ...` won't work, you have to use bracket in this case. as `df[column] = ...`

Comment: If you can include that in your answer along with any other distinctions I'll go ahead and accept. I just want to make sure it explains the distinction beyond the specific problem when using `.count`, since there appear to be other instances when they're not identical.